# Breaking out of the nested loop of 'while' and 'for'

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, tic-tac-toe

When I am using the `game_on= False`, it should end the game (end the while loop), but rather I found that the 2nd for loop is executed with the output of "Enter the position".
I want to exit from this nested loop (and end the game) when the if loop is evaluated to True. I also used the break statement in the if loop, but I found the same result.

```
game_on=True
while game_on:
    for i in range(1):
        position=int(input("Enter your position"))
        place_marker(game_board,p1_marker,position)
        display_board(game_board)
        if win_check(game_board,p1_marker):
            print("Player 1 wins")
            game_on=False


    for i in range(1):
        position=int(input("Enter your position"))
        place_marker(game_board,p2_marker,position)
        display_board(game_board)
        if win_check(game_board,p2_marker):
           print("Player 2 wins")
           game_on=False
```

Comment: Why do you even use the `for` loops here? The loops set `i` to `0`, run once, then exit. If you just removed them, and added a `break` after `game_on = False`, it would just work (and `game_on` itself could probably be removed, depending on your other logic).

Answer (score 1):

When you user `break` inside the if statement, you are also inside a for-loop, so you're just breaking the for-loop. `break` only exits the inner-most loop (in the case of nested loops) it can find. What you need is to use `break` when that while-loop you want to exit is the first loop `break` would find when you run it.

```
game_on=True
while game_on:
    for i in range(1):
        ....
        if win_check(game_board,p1_marker):
            print("Player 1 wins")
            game_on=False
    if(not game_on):
        break

    for i in range(1):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break out of the nested `for` loop you should use the a break statement (especially if you use something more repetive than `range(1)` in your real code), **and** if you don't want the second for loop to execute if the first for loop sets `game_on = False`, then you need and extra break before that:

```
game_on = True
while game_on:
    for i in range(1):
        position = int(input("Enter your position"))
        place_marker(game_board,p1_marker,position)
        display_board(game_board)
        if win_check(game_board,p1_marker):
            print("Player 1 wins")
            game_on = False
            break
    if not game_on:
        break
    for i in range(1):
        .
        .
```

However this often leads to code that is difficult to maintain and or read and there are several alternative strategies that might be better *depending on the circumstances and the rest of the code*:

#### 1) reduce second for loop execution

You can use one variable to control both the exit of the while and prevent the second for loop from executing:

```
test_times = 1
while test_times > 0:
    for i in range(test_times):
        position = int(input("Enter your position"))
        place_marker(game_board,p1_marker,position)
        display_board(game_board)
        if win_check(game_board,p1_marker):
            print("Player 1 wins")
            test_times = 0
            break
    for i in range(test_times):
        .
        .
```

#### 2) use a function and return from nested loops

```
def game():
    while True:
        for i in range(1):
            position = int(input("Enter your position"))
            place_marker(game_board,p1_marker,position)
            display_board(game_board)
            if win_check(game_board, p1_marker):
                print("Player 1 wins")
                return
        for i in range(1):
            .
            .

game()
```

#### 3) use a function and its return value to exit the outer loop:

```
def game_on():
    for i in range(1):
        position = int(input("Enter your position"))
        place_marker(game_board,p1_marker, position)
        display_board(game_board)
        if win_check(game_board, p1_marker):
            print("Player 1 wins")
            return False
    for i in range(1):
        position=int(input("Enter your position"))
        place_marker(game_board,p2_marker,position)
        display_board(game_board)
        if win_check(game_board,p2_marker):
            print("Player 2 wins")
            return False
    return True

while game_on():
    pass
```

#### 4) raise an exception to break out of nested loops

```
class GameOver(Exception):
    pass

try:
    while True:
        for i in range(1):
            position = int(input("Enter your position"))
            place_marker(game_board,p1_marker,position)
            display_board(game_board)
            if win_check(game_board, p1_marker):
                raise GameOver(1)
        for i in range(1):
            .
            .

except GameOver as e:
    print(f'Player {e} wins')
```

---

You should also consider using some code formatting tool (e.g. [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/), or my version of that tool [oitnb](https://pypi.org/project/oitnb/)), as your final `if` statement only indents 3 positions and there is general lack of space that makes your code (IMO) hard to read.

Comment: Thanks man for this beautiful explanation. I got everything right on my track. Thanks

Comment: @BalabhadraChand If this solves your issue, please consider this as the accpeted answer (clicking on the v mark to the left of the answer), that way others know your problem was solved, and what answer provided the solution